# How to hide the password in a request to login with OAuth?

Tags: android, symfony, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm doing an app with an OAuth2 login with my own server. The server is made with Symfony2 an the bundle FOSOAuthServerBundle.

The request to login the first time is like the next:

```
http://BASE_URL/oauth/v2/token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=password&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD
```

As you can see, the first time you make the request, the user are sending the password in a textplain way. Is there any method to avoid this?

I'm doing the request with Volley on Android, with StringRequest method:

```
StringRequest postReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, REQUEST, new Response.Listener<String>() {...
```

Comment: But, for https, the server need to support that, no?

Comment: Yes, the server has to support https, too.

Comment: Thanks, I will talk with the server support. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support HTTPS is generally a good idea these days.

It's also good practice not to put sensitive information in a `GET` request, since it will most likely appear in the server logs.

The recommended way to do that is to do a `POST` request instead, as it's highlighted by the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2):

> The client MUST use the HTTP "POST" method when making access token requests.

I noticed that it's your server and except you, only your provider might have access to it, but from a security perspective I would rather implement it with `POST`!

Comment: Thank you Carsten, I didn't know that tip about get/post.